# Hows to Add UserForm TextBox Value to Cell using MVP Method

Tags: excel, vba, mvp

I am trying to add a TextBox string value to cell `A1`. I am barely learning the basics of writing code using an MVP (Modal, View, Presenter), after reading [**this article**](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)  from Mathieu Guindon. I am getting a `Compile Error: Variable not defined` Error is found on `Sheet1.Range("A1") = clientName` Why?

Here is my code:

***Userform Name:***  "UserForm1"

*(code behind UserForm1)*

```
Option Explicit

Public Event OnRunReport()
Public Event OnExit()

Public Property Get clientName() As String
    clientName = clientNameBox.Text
End Property

Public Property Let clientName(ByVal value As String)
    clientNameBox.Text = value
End Property


Private Sub clientNameBox_Change()
clientName = clientNameBox.Text
End Sub

Private Sub exitButton_Click()
RaiseEvent OnExit
End Sub

Private Sub submit_Click()
    RaiseEvent OnRunReport
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
RaiseEvent OnRunReport
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

**Module1**

```
Option Explicit
Private objClientForm As UserForm1

Public Sub AddClientsToSheet()

Sheet1.Range("A1") = clientName  '******error line *******
End Sub


Public Sub showMainForm()

    If (objPresenter Is Nothing) Then
    Set objPresenter = New AddClientsToSheet
    End If

    objPresenter.show
End Sub
```

**ClassModule Name:** AddClientsToSheet

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objClientForm As UserForm1

Public Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set objClientForm = New UserForm1

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
Set objClientForm = Nothing
End Sub


Public Sub show()



If Not objClientForm.Visible Then

    objClientForm.show

End If

With objClientForm

    .Top = CLng((Application.Height / 2 + Application.Top) - .Height / 2)
    .Left = CLng((Application.Width / 2 + Application.Left) - .Width / 2)
End With
End Sub


Private Sub Hide()

If objClientForm.Visible Then objClientForm.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub objClientForm_OnExit()
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub objClientForm_OnRunReport()

AddClientsToSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: You never `Dim`ed the `clientName` Variable in Module1.

Comment: It is also a bit confusing how you are using `AddClientsToSheet`. You use it as method name and class name, I would try to avoid this if possible.

Comment: And I think there are some other problems in your code, for example the OnExit code should be inside the Userform, not inside the model. The `Hide` in the model makes no sense, as does the AddClientsToSheet.

Comment: As a tip, try making a very small example. Just a Userform with one TextBox and two buttons, Exit/OK. A Model and a Presenter/Controller. Name them accordingly and build them step for step.

Comment: There are a number of logical errors in the code, you might want to re-read the article. The error line that's marked is because `clientname` doesn't exist in `Module 1`; it's a property in UserForm1, but something in Module 1 won't "see" that without a reference to the UserForm1 class. It *might* be possible by preceding it with `objClientForm.`, depending on in what order things are happening. In addition you use `AddClientsToSheet` both as the name of a Sub and as the name of a class - they should be different.